# how to check if my server has been hacked

Tags: linux, ssh, server, logging

I have a couple of Ubuntu 16.04 servers. I want my server to be secure and ensure they can only be accessible by me and things. I check the auth.log and last. But I heard that hackers can change the output of them. Is there any way that I can make sure my server is 100% secured?

Comment: Keep it up to date

Comment: _There is no such thing as 100% secured_

Comment: If you want to make sure that your server is 100% secured, than unplug a network cable and power cable, that will be your success. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can make sure my server is 100% secured?

100%, absolutely not! Zero-day exploits will always be a concern, but you can reduce the number of open ports to the bare minimum, and those which you must have open, ensure their services are hardened. Hardening referring to using modern protocols or encryption ciphers, and disabling anything for legacy support. Also providing brute force protection.

For an OpenSSH server hardening includes:

- SSH protocol 2 only
- Opt for **RSA 4096 (or better)** or ED25519 exclusively for host keys

  - Generate new host keys, do not use default host keys
- Usage of `AllowUsers`
- Disable empty passwords
- Use a non-standard port (default is TCP 22)
- Fail2Ban; an intrusion prevention system

  - if 3 failed login attempts within 600 seconds then ban IP address for 1200 seconds
- Disable root login (if possible)

  - if not possible use a strong password or public key authentication is used; ensure brute force protection is enforced

[OpenSSH security and hardening](https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/) elaborates further on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use CIS CAT Benchmark, setup Open VAS, use complex passwords.

This all depends on how they are hosted.